# Is there a way to use gsutil cp to do multiple copies?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a set of source/destination pairs for which I could do:
`gsutil cp source1 dest1`
`gsutil cp source2 dest2`
etc.

Is there a way to do this for the whole group of transfers in one gsutil command?

Comment: I see that if all the copies will go to one destination it's possible...

From [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

You can pass a list of URLs (one per line) to copy on stdin instead of as command line arguments by using the -I option. This allows you to use gsutil in a pipeline to upload or download files / objects as generated by a program, such as:

some_program | gsutil -m cp -I gs://my-bucket
or:

some_program | gsutil -m cp -I ./download_dir
The contents of stdin can name files, cloud URLs, and wildcards of files and cloud URLs.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that with one gsutil command. The best I can recommend would be to write a script that runs the needed gsutil commands, possibly in parallel groups (e.g., 50 at once).

Comment: How can we gsutil cp two files?